# MDB2 autoprepare problem

Tags: php, mysql, mdb2

I am using mdb2 for my website and i ran into a problem. I have an order_no field in my table that i would like to have a default value like LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1. Is there a datatype that can be set for this kind of mysql functions for mdb2->autoExecute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because there is no way to provide (LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1) to the query as a placeholder which is what [AutoPrepare/AutoExecute does](http://elf.no-ip.org/php/peardoc/ja/package.database.mdb2.intro-auto.html).